# Mandatory fields in database

Tags: mysql

I have created a database table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
  password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL);
```

I then added to it like this, which failed as expected.

```
INSERT INTO test(name, password) VALUES ('test', NULL);
```

But then when I tried this it inserted without a problem:

```
INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES ('test');
```

I tried to create the table differently but it didn't create:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
 name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL );
```

So is there a way to get that to create an error when inserting?

Perhaps associated I think I will need to do something else to be able to validate data input into the database anyway and I think I saw something about constraints but I don't think these are supported in mysql? So is the null check and validation something I can't do the database with mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `MySQL` replaces implicit `NULL` values with zeroes (or empty strings for string datatypes).

You can work around this by enabling strict mode for your session or server:

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

or add

```
sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

under `[mysqld]` in your `my.cnf`.

Comment: Ahhh nice, it now has an error saying password doesn't have a default value. Thank you! One other small thing then from your answer: Where would I find the my.cnf file?